# How to show CDF uniquely determined from equation

Tags: cumulative-distribution-function, differential-equations

I have the following equation for a CDF that I would like to show is uniquely determined:

$$\frac{h_1(x)}{f(x)}=\int_x^a h_2(z)(F(z)-F(x))^k\;dF(z)$$
Here $F$ is the CDF and $f$ is the PDF, which I can already show exists for any possible $F$. It seems like such an $F$ must exist and even be unique given $h_1$ and $h_2$ are sufficiently well behaved.

I know that the maximum of the support has to be at $a$, so $F(a)=1$. Because, (a) $f$ at any point $x$ is uniquely determined by $F$ on $(x,a]$ and (b) assuming $h_2$ is bounded the integral will also be bounded, $F$ should clearly have not only a solution, but a unique solution.

What I've tried so far is assuming differentiatiability of $h_1$, so that because RHS must be differentiable and because $h_1$ is, LHS must be as well. Deriving and iterating this technique ($k$ times) eventually results in a ODE (assuming $h_1$ is $\mathcal{C}^k$), but it all gets very messy. This makes me think that sticking with the original integro-differential equation is best.

Comment: Hi, isn't it rather $\int .. dF(z)$ ?

Comment: And are you looking for solutions for arbitrary $k$ or one in particular ?

Comment: You are correct

Comment: Hoping for arbitrary $k\in N$ but it would be nice to have answers even for $k=1$